# how do you us summon item command in 1,.13

Tags: minecraft-commands

i have tried to us it like 
/summon item ~ ~2 ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:stone",count:1b}}

and all it says is

Answer (score 2):

You have a small mistake in the command.

```
/summon item ~ ~2 ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:stone",count:1b}}
                                                ^
```

Correctly:

```
/summon item ~ ~2 ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:stone",Сount:1b}}
                                                ^
```

Many commands are case sensitive.